# EF Property navigation

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I have a Silverlight app with Ria Service and EF. In my ViewModel i want to access a coleccion by navigating the entity relationship, in my service i have setup the query and i see that my collection is retrieved correctly, but in my Silverlight side in my ViewModel class it is lost. Anybody had come across with this issue?

The code in DomainService:

```
            var retVal = (from e in ObjectContext.embarques.Include("Bultos")
                  where e.nro_embarque == nroEmbarque && e.nro_sub_embarque == nroSubembarque
                  select e).FirstOrDefault();
        return retVal;
```

Above retVal have the desired result in Bultos, then in my ViewModel

```
EntityQuery<embarques> query = context.GetEmbarqueQuery(NroEmbarque, NroSubembarque);
            LoadOperation<embarques> op = context.Load(query);
            op.Completed += (sender, e) => {
                if (!op.HasError) {
                    Embarque = op.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (null != Embarque) {
                        Bultos = new ObservableCollection<Bultos>(Embarque.Bultos);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

Above Embarque.Bultos.Count = 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only peace i was missing here is to put  [Include] attribute in embarquesMetadata class:

```
internal sealed class embarquesMetadata
{
    ...
    [Include]                       
    public EntityCollection<Bulto> Bultos{ get; set; }
    ...
}
```

once included, everything like a charm